# how can I capture dynamically generated opportunity id and store it in a variable in test case using robot framework?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, robotframework

when i fill the form and save it, a unique id is generated. How can I store that value in a variable and use it in other test cases in robot framework using selenium.I am working with web bases application.

Comment: What did you try ? Any code example ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a variable that contains the unique ID, you can make it available to other test cases in the same suite with the [Set Suite Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable) keyword.

If you need the variable to be visible to test cases in other suites, you can use [Set Global variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Global%20Variable).

The links in the above go to the documentation for the keywords themselves. These keywords are also documented in the [robot framework users guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-set-test-suite-global-variable-keywords):

> Variables set with Set Suite Variable keyword are available everywhere within the scope of the currently executed test suite. Setting variables with this keyword thus has the same effect as creating them using the Variable table in the test data file or importing them from variable files. Other test suites, including possible child test suites, will not see variables set with this keyword.
>
> Variables set with Set Global Variable keyword are globally available in all test cases and suites executed after setting them. Setting variables with this keyword thus has the same effect as creating from the command line using the options --variable or --variablefile. Because this keyword can change variables everywhere, it should be used with care.